# When do we need $v1 in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, return-value, cpu-registers

We all know that usually a program will just return one value, but I have noticed that we have two value returning registers `$v0` and `$v1` in MIPS. The code I have seen all only have `$v0` but `$v1`, and I haven't found any assembly language example code that uses `$v1`.

Could anyone tell me why we have two $v registers in MIPS and show me a example of when it could be used?

Comment: The CPU registers don't just have a single usage. Nearly all of the registers can be used internally by a function for just about any purpose; and the more of them you've got, the better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why MIPS assembler has more that one register for return value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131986/why-mips-assembler-has-more-that-one-register-for-return-value)

Comment: examples where multiple return registers are used can easily been seen here [About returning more than one value in C/C++/Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31497152/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of uses for that

- Returning a value twice the length of the register (64-bit values in MIPS32 and 128-bit values in MIPS64) as @Martin Rosenau mentioned

  ```c
  long long mult(int x, int y) {
      return  (long long)x * y;
  }
  ```

  [Output assembly](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'long+long+mult(int+x,+int+y)+%7B%0A++++return++(long+long)x+*+y%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23ifdef+__SIZEOF_INT128__%0A__int128_t+mult128(long+long+x,+long+long+y)+%7B%0A++++return++(__int128_t)x+*+y%3B%0A%7D%0A%23endif%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:36.8713259307642,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:mips564el,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'MIPS64+gcc+5.4+(el)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0'),(h:compiler,i:(compiler:mips5el,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'MIPS+gcc+5.4+(el)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:63.1286740692358,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4):

  ```
  mult(int, int):
      mult    $4,$5
      mflo    $2
      mfhi    $3
      j       $31
      nop
  ```
- Returning structs that fit into 2 registers like these

  ```cpp
  typedef struct {
      int a, b;
  } ret_struct2x32;

  ret_struct2x32 return_struct2x32() {
      return ret_struct2x32{2, 3};
  }

  typedef struct {
      short a, b, c, d;
  } ret_struct4x16;

  ret_struct4x16 return_struct4x16() {
      return ret_struct4x16{(short)2, (short)0, (short)3, (short)0};
  }
  ```

  or returning tuples that appear in some languages like python

  ```python
  def func(x,y):
      # code to compute x and y
      return x,y

  a, b = 1, 2
  u, v = func(a, b)
  ```

  In C++ we have `std::pair` and `std::tuple`

  ```cpp
  std::pair<int, int> return_pair()
  {
      return std::make_pair(2, 3);
  }

  std::tuple<short, short, short, short> return_tuple()
  {
      return std::make_tuple((short)2, (short)0, (short)3, (short)0);
  }
  ```

  See the demo on [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwiIJ4GhAJ4bsHAAwBBOQqUrM6rQREAHBpmNnLFggaeYsAM1VBAmIRZAJ1AHY%2BC1U41QUIplJVACMNGMtIgBFVYkwCAH1g0PCuAA9ZLgyPD3yikrCCCqq8grEWYpCmlq4IAEpa6I94tsdiFjGu0ubK6uiuFNkOHJqLFezarx8/TEDG8KjM0cEEEiSU1JTkFPQ1rNz66aaAFnLaADZ7uoLn8LfPmMOn8CACPgMhsd4vUOlMDqD3l9ohBTud%2BotVCizsQCP1TCksWjZATUTi8Rtvqt1hZgugQCAnEw8MQNJpEilEsYgRNCozmRD1sNYtD2hMggQ6SAALZMADWmF5TOIEAxskGskyFOp5lp9McLjcWlJBBSxtN2JNQQtXJhPP1rgFWShcVtk110rlCvtmCgxvRJIteIDRODZNM6s1OSk/UY0gArFJSCxpKZE6hpJp%2BPwgqJxHY5LREwQU9GY7KQLJTAA6D4ATgAHI3ax9aC8PpXa3HIrGpC9E8mpKnSOmpInBCB8cXB9HSHBYEg0FKnHpMGQKBBF8vXMRpXgnII4x8XpgGKR/HoCKvxxBUiXSKkFExiAZpIXSIupZgWAQAPIsBgvtOpBYDKbCuHe%2BD5OEeAAG6YOOQGYOUmDIDokhSG%2BiQnne%2BipMQT4GJoGDoW%2BIR4FKr4zswbAoFmvCMHgqTjpAMaoE4uioCwCEALQ/rIqjcbSGjZJwvD8LQb7CGIEh0DGDDxv2d4jgAsgAkgACgAykeqjAMgyCqHGVYvJiJ79JiuCECQ6hcLI9CqERS4rsQNl2eZmZibwRYljGEALqgTnbuQlCbs5u77nGJ5nheV6ULeQEPiwBGUe%2BAWft%2Bf4ARBmCgcA4FAZBKG6HBCFDkhKFoSlWHyUBuH4c%2BRFYClZEURhVGsOwdECLhzEDMO7F4JxPF8QJQmyCJXUSWOuYybQckKUmSnSGpWm6fphnGaZDDmRAllEC5BYpI5W6rq5XDuV13nTr5/mBauwUbgFJ07koHUfKY%2BLngwl7ENe8VDolyVtalUrpb%2B/6AUOIEdflUPMkVsHwXe5WoZeVXfthtWMfVhHEc1xDkZRckdbRnndYxvWsQNQ3SLx/GCRKwmiXwvBTUIM2SHNPYJotQEjuU9YfNxOmvWwqgfFW1amBZ%2BD7a59nHc5rlqg5l2kFOqb9GWIB1lWlYSbQpiyPWcayHWpgvD2fa80OI5jiAiwa6WPZcIpfPSFdmsxnBv2DcmLxAA%3D%3D). Unfortunately the gcc version for MIPS is too old and can't make use the struct-in-register optimization, so look at the x86 output and you'll see that the whole tuples are returned in only a single instruction

It's similar to the pair (E/R)DX:(E/R)AX in x86 to return a value double the size of the registers

See also

- [About returning more than one value in C/C++/Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31497152/995714)
- [Why MIPS assembler has more that one register for return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20131986/995714)

Answer (score 2):

Another use case is returning 64-bit numbers on 32-bit MIPS (or 128-bit numbers in 64-bit MIPS).

Answer (score 1):

I can think of plenty of examples, but it's probably just up to your discretion. The best example is probably a function that returns a value in $v0 and may set an error code in $v1.