# Why MIPS assembler has more that one register for return value?

Tags: assembly, mips

I just started learning MIPS assembler and realized that there are [two registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Compiler_register_usage) for return values.

First of all I thought that it was implemented because there are languages that might return more then one value (but then limiting the number of registers to 2 doesn't make much sense). Still as [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/203471/why-do-most-programming-languages-only-support-returning-a-single-value-from-a-f) Q&A suggests, most modern programming languages use exactly one return value, although emphasizing the word "modern" which implies that in past there were languages that returned multiple function values, is this the reason MIPS has 2 return registers, if yes, why only 2?

Comment: [About returning more than one value in C/C++/Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31497152/995714)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be able to return 64-bit values on a 32-bit CPU - e. g. double precision floating points and 64-bit integers. Even mainstream languages with a single return value have datatypes larger than a single register.

Comment: Does this mean that on a 64 bit machine there is no reason to have 2 return registers? Unless there are data types bigger than 64 bits, but then how does it handle object that are bigger that 64bits?

Comment: On 64-bit machines, those two registers are still designated as return value to retain compatibility. Note that one can still use them as scratch, as long as they are assigned at the end of the function.

Comment: Okay. But what happens with bigger object that are turned by value? 2 registers might not be enough for them.

Comment: For those, the caller allocates a place on the stack and passes a hidden pointer argument. The function writes the data there. This is not a part of the CPU architecture proper - it's a compiler implementation detail or a part of the ABI.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie in 64-bit machines they can be used to return [128-bit values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) or other uses. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204430/when-do-we-need-v1-in-mips/24230036#24230036)